# Scilab: how to read a txt file with different number of columns

Tags: csv, text, scilab

I have a txt file with 132 lines (characters and flots). However, from line 1 to 106 there are 10 columns, after that 11 columns. Than I couldn't use read function. I also tried `fscanfMat` but I think it only works for real numbers. Like:

```
Line 1:106 -> Name   Age   Sex    Phone ....
Line 107:132 -> Name Surname Age  Sex Phone ....
```

I´d like to read the file and search between lines and rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is just one file I would suggest that you open it in a text editor and then separate the two sections with different columns. Then use `csvRead` to extract the data. Otherwise, if you have a lot of files like this then use `mgetstr` to export the specific length you want to extract from the file into a string (Also look into `mscanf`). Then use `csvTextScan` to extract the CSV data into matrix format.